# Individual Photo Backup : New Google Photos

Tags: google-photos

I've enabled Auto-backup in the new Google Photos app. And I have excluded some folders from being backed-up. But this seems to be all or nothing. I want some of the photos in those excluded folders to be backed up. Any way to do that?

Comment: Nope, not possible. You can upload the photos manually, but there would be no point specifying certain filenames to be automatically backed up, because they would never change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been trying to do what you're asking for a while and I think I've found a way. Upload the pic to Google Drive and go into pic info. From there click 'send to' and select 'upload to photos'. The pic/pics you uploaded should be in the 'photos' section of Google Photos. After that you can delete it from Drive. 
Hope this helps